# How to interact with 2 databases in C using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, c

I am currently working on a project where I have to count runners. At some point, I have to transfer the data from my local Database (mysqlLocal) to the one of the High School I'm working in (mysqlLycee).

I think doing this was a good idea, but for some reason I have a segfault when executing the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MYSQL mysqlLocal;
    MYSQL_RES *result = NULL;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    char requete[150];
    int num_champs;
    char noParticipant[5];
    char kmParcourus[3];
    mysql_init(&mysqlLocal);
    if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysqlLocal,"127.0.0.1","root","debianCCF","localCCF",0,NULL,0))printf("Error on first connect");

    sprintf(requete,"SELECT NO_PARTICIPANT, KMPARCOURUS FROM PARTICIPANTS WHERE NO_COURSE = %s",argv[5]);
    if(!mysql_query(&mysqlLocal,requete))printf("Error on first query");
    result = mysql_use_result(&mysqlLocal);
    num_champs=mysql_num_fields(result);
    mysql_close(&mysqlLocal);

    MYSQL mysqlLycee;
    mysql_init(&mysqlLycee);
    if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysqlLycee,argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],0,NULL,0))printf("Error on second connect");
    int i;
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))){
        unsigned long *lengths;     
        lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
        for(i=0;i<num_champs;i++){
            if(i==0)sprintf(noParticipant,"%.*s", (int) lengths[i], row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
            if(i==1)sprintf(kmParcourus,"%.*s", (int) lengths[i], row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
        }   
        sprintf(requete,"UPDATE PARTICIPANTS SET KMPARCOURUS=%s WHERE NO_PARTICIPANT=%s",kmParcourus,noParticipant);
        if(!mysql_query(&mysqlLycee,requete))printf("Error on second query");

    }
    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(&mysqlLycee);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm working on Debian 8, and compiling with the following command :

`gcc updateLycee.c -o updateLycee -lmysqlclient -L/usr/lib64/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql;`

EDIT: added mysql checks, but still segfault when starting the program.

Comment: Add error checking for every MySQL calls please.

Comment: I modified the code to have mysql checks, but anyway, when I execute the program the segfault appears.

Comment: Spaces and newlines are cheap; use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You close your connection to the local database, and then later try to fetch rows from a result set associated with that connection.  That will not work.

If you want to transfer data from one DB to the other then you must either

- first slurp all the wanted data from one DB into memory (fetch all the rows and store the contents you need in ordinary arrays, for instance), OR
- hold connections to both databases open at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I tried with holding both connections but I also had troubles with it. But storing data is in fact a solution I did not think about !